# Button click event in user control gets called automacitally when parent page is loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, `parent.aspx`, which includes a user control, `csForm.ascx`. This user control is just a simple form with a send button at the end. I am also using `Modal Popup Extender` from `AjaxToolKit` to display the form.

**Parent.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scmg" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="btnCS" PopupControlID="csForm$pnlPopup"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="csForm$btnSend" 
CancelControlID="csForm$imgBtnClose" PopupDragHandleControlID="csForm$pnlPopup" 
Drag="true" DropShadow="true" />
```

**csForm.ascx.cs**

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendEmail(); //this gets automatically called when parent page is loaded. 
}
```

The problem I have got is `sendEmail()` gets called automatically when parent.aspx page is loaded. Is there a way to stop that? I'd like to call it only when `Send` button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        sendEmail(); //this gets automatically called when parent page is loaded. 
    }
}
```

This is not the right solution, but will fix this problem.